# change the color of jpanel from another one

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jpanel

I have a frame that consists of two  `JPanels`

`Panel1` contains a button, when the button is clicked i want the panel2 to be changed in color and become red and this didn't happen

So any help and explanation on how to change the color of a panel from another panel

```
 public class MyForm extends JFrame {
            public MyForm() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    // setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        JButton btn = new JButton("Change Color");
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Sqsq");
                Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
                panel2.setBackground(Color.red);
                panel2.repaint();

            }
        });
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {
    public Panel2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        setBackground(Color.black);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyForm form = new MyForm();
    // form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    form.setSize(500, 500);
    form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    form.setVisible(true);

}
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, in you `btn` `actionPerformed` method, you are creating a **new** `Panel2` which is not the same reference as the one added to the frame, hence, nothing will change...

You need to pass `Panel1` and reference to the component you want to update...

```
class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    private JComponent changeMe;

    public Panel1(JComponent changeMe) {
        this.changeMe = changeMe;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        JButton btn = new JButton("Change Color");
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Sqsq");
                if (changeMe != null) {
                    changeMe.setBackground(Color.red);
                    changeMe.repaint();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

You may need to request that the parent container be repainted instead, but see how this goes...